# How to SSH into two different Linux SSH hosts (docker) with same IP and different SSH port numbers

Tags: docker, openssh

Following is the IP and port number configuration - all hosts are running some version of Ubuntu or the other

```
HostA : 192.168.1.200

DockerHostA (running in HostA) : 172.17.0.8

MyLaptop : 192.168.1.201

In the docker specification, I have mapped port 22 (of DockerHostA) to port 9090 of (HostA).
```

I can connect to HostA by

```
ssh user@192.168.1.200
```

this adds an entry into the *~/.ssh/known_hosts* file.

I can also connect to the DockerHostA like

```
ssh -p 9090 user@192.168.1.200
```

this also adds an entry (second) in the *known_hosts* file. After this happens, I can only connect to the DockerHostA and I am unable to ssh into HostA.

```
ssh user@192.168.1.200
ssh -p 9090 user@192.168.1.200
```

both of these ssh into DockerHostA.

I can delete the known_hosts file and this allows ssh connection to both hosts exactly once, before the problem happens again.

```
~/.ssh/known_hosts has two entries
|1|883fTHa....
|1|t89sTmV....
```

So, my questions are

1. How can I connect to two different hosts with the same IP address but different ports?
2. Can I do anything to route traffic for ip:172.17.0.8 (DockerHostA), so I can directly ping that IP address?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

I will assume you fully understand the purpose of the fingerprint check and what are the risks of automatically acknowledging new fingerprints or considering the fingerprint changes legitimate:

```
ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@192.168.1.200
ssh -p 9090 -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@192.168.1.200
```

---

**Question 2:**

I assume your docker containers are launched on the docker-bridge network. This is a separate subnet that usually defaults to 172.17.0.0/16. By default there is no route from 192.168.0.0/24 to 172.17.0.0/16.

You can basically create any routes and iptables rules you need, but usually you want to let docker manage everything: When you use the `docker run -p <src>:<dst>`, docker automatically creates a forwarding rule from your `host:<src>` to your `container:<dst>`

Answer (score 0):

You may map both of your SSH containers port (so 22) to arbitrary ports on your host. By this way, you'll be able to do this for example

Container 1

```sh
ssh -p 9000 user@localhost
```

Container 2

```sh
ssh -p 9001 user@localhost
```